# MySQL Check if Business Hours Exist for Each Day of the Week

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need a query to check if the business has business hours set for **EACH** day of the week (dayofweek `IDs` are 1-7)

It will be used something like this:

```
hours_check = MySQL query will check if hours exists for each day of the week

if hours_check true:
    return X 
else:
    return Y
```

I have these 3 tables:

```
BUSINESS
id ..
name ..

DAYOFWEEK
id ..
name ..

HOURS
id ..
business_id ..
dayofweek_id ..
```

I know how to check for one day with something like:

`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM hours WHERE business_id = 1 and dayofweek_id = 1)`

How do I check for each day without running a separate query for each day?

Comment: using an ORM would make this simpler ... just a heads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table BUSINESS ( id   int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key, 
                        name char(20) );
create table DAYOFWEEK ( id   int not NULL, 
                         name char(3) );
create table HOURS ( id           int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key, 
                     business_id  int NOT NULL references BUSINESS(id),
                     dayofweek_id int NOT NULL references DAYOFWEEK(id),
                     hour_range   char(20) );

insert into BUSINESS (id, name) values (1000, 'Walmart'), 
                                       (1001, 'RadioShack'), 
                                       (1002, 'AlwaysClosed');

insert into DAYOFWEEK (id, name) values 
    (1,'Mon'), (2,'Tue'), (3,'Wed'), (4,'Tue'),
    (5,'Fri'), (6,'Sat'), (7,'Sun');

insert into HOURS (business_id, dayofweek_id, hour_range) values
    (1000, 2, '08:00 - 10:00'),    
    (1000, 2, '12:00 - 19:00'),
    (1000, 6, '09:00 - 21:00'),
    (1001, 3, '07:00 - 17:00');

-- Get an overview which shop is open when:
select b.name, d.name as day, h.hour_range 
  from HOURS h inner join DAYOFWEEK d on h.dayofweek_id=d.id
       left join BUSINESS b on b.id=h.business_id
       order by b.name, d.id, h.hour_range;

-- Get an overview for each day:
select d.name as day, b.name, h.hour_range 
  from DAYOFWEEK d left join HOURS h on h.dayofweek_id=d.id
       left join BUSINESS b on b.id=h.business_id
       order by d.id, b.name, h.hour_range;
```

The two selects will result in

```
+------------+------+---------------+
| name       | day  | hour_range    |
+------------+------+---------------+
| RadioShack | Wed  | 07:00 - 17:00 |
| Walmart    | Tue  | 08:00 - 10:00 |
| Walmart    | Tue  | 12:00 - 19:00 |
| Walmart    | Sat  | 09:00 - 21:00 |
+------------+------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
+------+------------+---------------+
| day  | name       | hour_range    |
+------+------------+---------------+
| Mon  | NULL       | NULL          |
| Tue  | Walmart    | 08:00 - 10:00 |
| Tue  | Walmart    | 12:00 - 19:00 |
| Wed  | RadioShack | 07:00 - 17:00 |
| Tue  | NULL       | NULL          |
| Fri  | NULL       | NULL          |
| Sat  | Walmart    | 09:00 - 21:00 |
| Sun  | NULL       | NULL          |
+------+------------+---------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Sorry if not being clear, but I only need to check if the business hours are set and exist for EACH day of the week. Your query will only display already set hours. This is not for visual control but for the app to determine if the user can continue. `If hours exists for each day of the week, then do X else do Y`

Comment: Ok, misunderstood that. Then this could help. It shows on how many distinct days a shop is open. If the number is 7, then it's open all days.
    `select count(distinct d.id), b.name
      from BUSINESS b left join HOURS h on b.id=h.business_id
           left join DAYOFWEEK d on h.dayofweek_id=d.id
           group by b.name order by b.name;`

Comment: Or even simplify it to `select count(distinct h.dayofweek_id) from HOURS h where h.business_id=1001;` if you know the business_id already.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The `count` is exactly what I need. For some reason, I couldn't think of that. It has been a long week :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SQL IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

```
SELECT 
EXISTS(
    SELECT id FROM hours WHERE business_id = 1 and dayofweek_id IN [1,2,3..etc]
)
```

Assuming you just want to make sure that there exists an hour during the week that they are open.

Comment: David, thanks for the feedback. Sorry if not being clear, but I need to check that the hours are set for EACH day of the week. Your query only checks if there are any hours set.

Comment: As PerlDog said:

`days_set = select count(distinct h.dayofweek_id) from hours as h where     h.business_id=?;`

Should return the amount of unique days of the week a company has hours set. You could either compare that to 7 or wrap it in a function that returns true/false based on that.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select hours.*, dayofweek.name AS day
from dayofweek
inner join hours on hours.dayofweek_id = dayofweek.id
where hours.business_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Sorry if not being clear, but I need to check that the hours are set for EACH day of the week. Your query will only select all values for the business.